# how do I handle sockets which is readable but recv nothing?

Tags: python, sockets, http, https, python-sockets

Recently I've been writing a http/https proxy using socket on python, and I use select to decide whether a socket is ready to recv or send, something like this:

```
inputs = [sock1, sock2...]
outputs = [sock1, sock2...]
while True:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
    for s in readable:
        do something with s.recv()
    for s in writable:
        do something with s.send()
```

and I notice that sometimes a socket is readable but when I do s.recv() it returns empty. And since I have a while True loop outside so it gets nothing again and again. I tried to close the socket at first:

```
data = s.recv(4096) 
if not data:
    inputs.remove(s)
    s.close()
```

but after a while some socket comes alive and they can't send msg to me because I've already closed it.
Does that mean I shouldn't close it? So what should I do with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to reopen a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410723/is-there-a-way-to-reopen-a-socket)

Comment: @Joe No, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a socket in the receive list returns zero bytes on `recv`, it means that the socket has been closed from the other side. It will never receive data again and should be shutdown and closed on your side too.

You way "some socket comes alive" - its not the socket on the other side of this connection, that one has already shutdown.

Comment: I check my log again with "some socket comes alive", it is the client side that send some msg to proxy, wanting me to forward to  the server side, which already been closed by me.

Comment: Does that mean it will get an  error like ECONNRESET even if I don't close the server side and try to send the msg?

Comment: @DirkPaul - I'm embarrased to admit I don't remember which error you'd get. In this case, you received 0 meaning the other side gracefully shut the socket down. If its side tried to send again I don't think it would be ECONNRESET, it woudl be perhaps ESHUTDOWN? I used to know this stuff!